# Executing multiple mysql queries in python script

Tags: python, mysql

I'm attempting to do more than one MySql query in my python script, and I'm doing all the things that I think I'm supposed to, but it's still not doing anything to my `table_a`.  Any insight?

```
import MySQLdb
conn = MySQLdb.connect("abc","bcd","cde","def")
x = conn.cursor()

try:
   operation = '''
    insert into table_a 
    (id, ip, hostname, username) 
    select distinct id, ip, hostname, username
    from table_b;

    update table_a 
    set 
    purpose = 'test purpose'
    , department = 'test department'
    where
    hostname = 'sample'
'''



   for result in x.execute(operation,multi = True):
      pass

   conn.commit()
except:
   conn.rollback()

conn.close()
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? You have a typo in your query, which might be your problem - you have `insert into table_a (id, ip, hsotname, username)`, but then you seem to refer to that column as `hostname` elsewhere.